# Finding big string sequence between two keywords within multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with the format of

```
sjaskdjajldlj_abc:  
cdf_asjdl_dlsf1:  
    dfsflks %jdkeajd  
sdjfls:  
    adkfld  %dk_.(%sfj)sdaj, %kjdflajfs  
    afjdfj _ajhfkdjf  
    zjddjh -15afjkkd  
    xyz
```

and I want to find the text in between the string `_abc:` in the first line and `xyz` in the last line. 
I have already tried print

```
re.findall(re.escape("*_abc:")+"(*)"+re.escape("xyz"),line)
```

But I got `null`.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the `*` in the first part of your pattern for? Why is the end `ret` rather than `xyz`?

Comment: The first star is for the previous charachters before _abc:

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the requirement correctly:

```
a1=re.search(r'_abc(.*)xyz',line,re.DOTALL)
print a1.group(1)
```

Use re.DOTALL which will enable . to match a newline character as well.

Comment: It might be more clear to use the alternative spelling `re.DOTALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You used `re.escape` on your pattern when it contains special characters, so there's no way it will work.

```
>>>>re.escape("*_abc:")
'\\*_abc\\:'
```

This will match the actual phrase `*_abc:`, but that's not what you want.

Just take the re.escape calls out and it should work more or less correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a misunderstanding about what the `*` symbol means in a regular expression. It doesn't mean "match anything", but rather "repeat the previous thing zero or more times".

To match any string, you need to combine `*` with `.`, which matches any single character (almost, more on this later). The pattern `.*` matches any string of zero or more characters.

So, you could change your pattern to be `.*abc(.*)xyz` and you'd be most of the way there. However, if the prefix and suffix only exist once in the text the leading `.*` is unnecessary. You can omit it and just let the regular expression engine handle skipping over any unmatched characters before the `abc` prefix.

The one remaining issue is that you have multiple lines of text in your source text. I mentioned above that the `.` patter matches character, but that's not entirely true. By default it won't match a newline. For single-line texts that doesn't matter, but it will cause problems for you here. To change that behavior you can pass the flag `re.DOTALL` (or its shorter spelling, `re.S`) as a third argument to `re.findall` or `re.search`. That flag tells the regular expression system to allow the `.` pattern to match any character including newlines.

So, here's how you could turn your current code into a working system:

```
import re

def find_between(prefix, suffix, text):
    pattern = r"{}.*{}".format(re.escape(prefix), re.escape(suffix))
    result = re.search(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
    if result:
        return result.group()
    else:
        return None # or perhaps raise an exception instead
```

I've simplified the pattern a bit, since your comment suggested that you want to get the whole matched text, not just the parts in between the prefix and suffix.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. Do you know a neat way to include the prefix and suffix too in the output. I can attach them to the output of the find_between method but I thought maybe there is a better way to do so.

Comment: @user2628665: Sure, that's actually easier! I'll edit my answer.